# How to fix: "@angular/fire"' has no exported member 'AngularFireModule'.ts(2305) ionic, firebase, angular

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm trying to connect my app with a firebase db, but I receive 4 error messages on app.module.ts:

```
'"@angular/fire"' has no exported member 'AngularFireModule'.ts(2305),
'"@angular/fire/storage"' has no exported member 'AngularFireStorageModule'.ts(2305)
'"@angular/fire/database"' has no exported member 'AngularFireDatabaseModule'.ts(2305)
'"@angular/fire/auth"' has no exported member 'AngularFireAuthModule'.ts(2305)
```

here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "gescable",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1202.5",
    "@angular-devkit/architect-cli": "^0.1202.5",
    "@angular/common": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.0.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~12.1.1",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.5.2",
    "ajv": "^8.6.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.4.2",
    "firebase": "^7.24.0",
    "rxfire": "^6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~12.0.1",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.16.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.16.1",
    "eslint": "^7.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1200.0",
    "firebase-tools": "^9.0.0",
    "fuzzy": "^0.1.3",
    "inquirer": "^6.2.2",
    "inquirer-autocomplete-prompt": "^1.0.1",
    "open": "^7.0.3",
    "jsonc-parser": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}
```

And here is my app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';
import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ClientPageModule } from './client/client.module';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/storage';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/database';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    ClientPageModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebaseConfig),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule
  ],
  providers: [{ provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Here is my tsonfig.ts file

```
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"]
  },
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
    "strictInjectionParameters": true,
    "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
    "strictTemplates": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`@angular/fire`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire) `^7.0.4` does not match this one dependency: `firebase` `^7.24.0`.

Either you depend on `firebase` [`9.0.2`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/firebase/v/9.0.2) - or downgrade to `@angular/fire` `^6.1.5`.

Just see the documentation which I've linked, it clearly states that.

```
"@angular/fire": "~7.0.4",
"firebase": "~9.0.2",
```

---

Besides, `@ionic` had been superseded by `@capacitor` and `devkit` goes into `devDependencies`.

Answer (score 96):

You need to add "compat" like this

```
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire/compat";
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
```

Comment: tks @AchrafBj . Here is the error message: {moduleIdentifier: 'c:\dev\gescable\gescable\node_modules\@angular-dev…ular\fire\fesm2015\angular-fire-compat-storage.js', moduleName: './node_modules/@angular/fire/fesm2015/angular-fire-compat-storage.js', loc: '10:0-43', message: "Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/c…ble\gescable\node_modules\@angular\fire\fesm2015'"}

Comment: This was the solution for me when using @ionic/angular 6.0.3, Angular 13.2.2, and @angular/fire 7.2.1

Comment: Thanks.Adding compat solves the problem.

Answer (score 10):

First, change the imports by adding compact

```
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';
```

If that doesn't solve the problem type ctrl+Z
and check compatibility
Angular     Firebase and    AngularFire
13              9          ^7.2
12              9           ^7.0
12             7,8          ^6.1.5

Comment: I there any document available of the changes.

Comment: On this link you can see the compatibility https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire

Comment: and here to you can see the compatibility and about @angular/fire/compat https://github.com/angular/angularfire

Comment: Here to also here we talk about the upgrade concerning the addition of the compact https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Answer (score 8):

Tks very much to  @AchrafBj and @martin-Zeitler. Every thing works correctly:

1. I upgraded to "firebase": "~9.0.2" with npm i firebase@9.0.2
2. I made some corrections in the app.module.ts file:

`````
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
import { AngularFireStorageModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireDatabaseModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/database';````

here is the link https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Enjoy!!!!
`````

Answer (score 4):

Someone else had a same mistake? you may solve that with this imports on you angular module:

```
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/compat/firestore';
import { AngularFireStorageModule, BUCKET } from '@angular/fire/compat/storage';
import { AngularFireModule } from "@angular/fire/compat";
```

For the @angular/fire V ^9.15.0

Regards!